# How to have a relationship with a table with composite key?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a `course_subject` table in which each subject can be associated to many courses.

```
Course Subject
C1      S1
C1      S2
C1      S4
C2      S1
C3      S1
```

and a `student` table in which, each student can have only one course.

```
 Student Course
    S1       C1
    S2       C1
    S3       C2
    S4       C3
```

My `CourseSubject` class is as following

```
@Entity
Class CourseSubject {
    @Id
    String Course;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    Subject subject;
    ...
}
```

My `Student` class is as following

```
@Entity
Class Student {
   @Id
   long id;
   String fname;
   String lname;
   String course;
   ...
}
```

In other words, each student has only one course but each course has multiple subjects, that implies each student is related to multiple subjects through his associated course.

I need to know how to create queries like:

**Query:** Show all students who are participating in subject S1.

**Result:** So based on above records it should show all students who are enrolled in C1,C2 and C3 because all of them have subject S1.

(Please note, in Student class, I just have course names)

I suppose, **one option would be** to have query like

```
Select * from Student WHERE course IN 
                                     (Select course from 
                                           CourseSubject 
                                           WHERE 
                                           subject.name = 'S1')
```

Comment: Which table is the owner in the relationship, `CourseSubject` or `Student`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I suppose Student is owner, as each student has only one course but multiple subjects.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my issue is each student has one course only but indirectly has multiple subjects. (All subjects of his associated course)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen question is updated. thanks